# How dynamically change S3 path inside DefinitionBody

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

My code currently is working like this

```
DefinitionBody:
  'Fn::Transform':
    Name: AWS::Include
    Parameters:
      Location:            
        Fn::Sub: s3://${Bucket}/${AWS::StackName}/${File}
        # Note: Bucket and File comes from Parameters in this case
```

Now I try to get {$File} dynamically using FindInMap

```
    'Fn::Transform':
       Name: AWS::Include
       Parameters:
       Location: !Sub
         - s3://${value-from-parameters-section}/${AWS::StackName}/${spec}
         - { spec: !FindInMap [ "Config", "type", "file"]}
```

But is throwing me this error:

`Failed to digest functions within transform parameters, intrinsic functions in transform block must only contain parameter values or stack metadata`

So, How I can achieve to dynamically change the File name inside the DefinitonBody?

Answer (score 1):

You can't do this, it is **not supported**. [AWS docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/intrinsic-function-reference-transform.html#intrinsic-function-reference-transform-supported-functions) explicitly states that no intrinsic functions are supported:

> **Supported functions  None**. CloudFormation passes any intrinsic function calls included in Fn::Transform to the specified macro as **literal strings**.

You can re-design your function to use [custom resources](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/template-custom-resources.html) instead of macros. This way you can do whatever you wish.

Comment: Oh thanks for the response, but I was wondering what the custom resource should looks like, I mean I need to create a custom resource for replace all the element which contains this, in this case AWS::Serverless::Api or just the  Fn::Transform section?

Comment: @jam you can replace entire recource that you create, and construct it in a custom resource instead.

Answer (score 1):

In this case, I think the message is self-explanatory

```
Failed to digest functions within transform parameters, intrinsic functions in transform block must only contain parameter values or stack metadata
```

Only metadata or parameters are allowed, that is the reason this works

```
DefinitionBody:
  'Fn::Transform':
  Name: AWS::Include
  Parameters:
    Location:            
      Fn::Sub: s3://${Bucket}/${AWS::StackName}/${StackType}
```

In case somebody needs a workaround I just remove the mapping section and rename the name of the files to match the type I want, something like this

```
Parameters:
  StackType:
    Type: String
    AllowedValues:
      - typeA
      - typeB
  Bucket:
    Type: String
```

Then I just use this sub to get the DefinitionBody like this:

```
DefinitionBody:
    'Fn::Transform':
      Name: AWS::Include
      Parameters:
        Location:
          Fn::Sub: s3://${Bucket}/${AWS::StackName}/${StackType}-API.yaml
```

This will resolve like this:

```
s3://example-bucket/name-of-stack/typeA-API.yaml 
or
s3://example-bucket/name-of-stack/typeB-API.yaml
```

So now I just need to have these files named in that way on the S3, this is similar to what mapping should do, but for now, is not supported, this will achieve what I want, is not perfect but did the trick, still remain the confusion because I think the documentation is inaccurate